# JSON Returning Null in PHP

Tags: php, json

Here is the two scripts I have

Script 1:

```
  <?

include('config.php');
$json = $_POST['payload'];
$fine = var_dump($json);
$secret = "78f12668216b562a79d46b170dc59f695070e532";
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $json);
fwrite($fp, $fine);
fclose($fp);

if(sha1($json . $secret) == $_POST['signature']) {
    $conversion_id = md5(($obj['amount']));
    echo "OK";
    echo $conversion_id;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO completed (`id`,`uid`,`completedid`) VALUES ('','".$obj['uid']."','".$conversion_id."')");
} else {

}
?>
```

Script 2:

```
<?
$json = $_POST['payload'];
$secret = "78f12668216b562a79d46b170dc59f695070e532";
$obj = json_decode($json);

if(sha1($json+$secret) == $_POST['signature']) {
    print "OK";
} else {

}
?>
```

The problem here is that it is returning all NULL values. I am not an expert with JSON so I have no idea what is going on here. I really have no way of testing it because the information is coming from an outside website sending information such as this:

```
{
  payload: {
    uid: "900af657a65e",
    amount: 50,
    adjusted_amount: 25
  },
  signature: "4dd0f5da77ecaf88628967bbd91d9506"
}
```

The site allows me to test the script, but because json_decode is providing NULL values it will not get through the signature block.

According to Google Chrome's Dev Tools the response it sends when I try to test the script from their server is `{"error":"The start uri returned a non-200 response."}` that is all of the information it gives me it does not state what is being sent, only received

Is there a way I can test it myself? Or is there a simple error in this script that I may have just looked over?

EDIT

I set up a file to write the information being passed and this is what is being sent by their server

```
{"job_id":1337,"job_title":"CrowdFlower test job","amount":30,"uid":"inspire","adjusted_amount":50}
```

at first there was slashes so I added `stripslashes()` to the `$json` variable and that obviously got rid of the slashes, but once it hits the `json_decode()` it does not pull the information is there something wrong with the information being passed?

Comment: Try starting with: var_dump($_POST); Also, valid json uses strings for property names.

Comment: Could you show the code you use to request the response from the server?

Comment: @budwiser All of that is automatic, it is for Crowd Flower, when a user completes a task their server sends the information, my server just accepts it. That is why I am having so much trouble figuring it out.

Comment: @kira423 Could you do a `var_dump($json)` **before** using the `stripslashes` and add the output to your question?

Comment: @budwiser it returns nothing, it doesn't add any text to the text file.

Comment: Of course it returns somethings. Like you said yourself: "I set up a file to write the information being passed and this is what is being sent by their server..."
`{"job_id":1337,"job_title":"CrowdFlower test job","amount":30,"uid":"inspire","adjusted_amount":50}`
There has to be something.

Comment: It seems that you have some basic misunderstanding error here because the bit you posted earlier is pure valid `json`.

Comment: @budwiser I have updated script 1 to what I have now that is inserting into the text file, the only thing that is actually going into the file is `$json` the variable `$fine` is not adding anything extra into the text file.

Comment: @kira423 Okay, what if you do `var_dump($_POST)` right after including config.php. This way we would know that the problem is for sure in either on the server sending you the message (not likely scenario, if it's a (maybe big) production server) in question or some error in your script handling the request. I'm still curious to see how to get the response. If required, we have to create a chat room for this case. I want to solve it :D

Comment: @budwiser it is still producing nothing, I took out the write `$json` so it would only write `$fine` which I changed to how you suggested above, and now the file is just blank. If you would like to just move to chat please let me know, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17980/discussion-between-kira423-and-budwiser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how the outside site send the data, but my guess is

`$_POST['payload']` **is already an array**, and you don't need to decode it. Just use `var_dump($_POST)` to check it.

For example, the data is sent by the outside site like below with javascript:

```
var data = {
  payload: {
    uid: "900af657a65e",
    amount: 50,
    adjusted_amount: 25
  },
  signature: "4dd0f5da77ecaf88628967bbd91d9506"
};

$.ajax({
  url: ....,
  data: data,
  //....

});
```

Comment: unfortuntley using `var_dump($_POST)` will not work because when I add it to the script and use their site to test it, it tells me that the script produced something other than a 200 OK response. I tried changing `$obj['uid']` to `$_POST['uid']` and it is still showing blank in the database so I am not sure as how to check it.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to [validate](http://jsonlint.com/) your JSON, I get the following error:

```
Parse error on line 1:
{    payload: {        u
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

And are you trying to concatenate or add?

```
if(sha1($json+$secret) == $_POST['signature'])
```

If concatenation, replace the `+` with `.` as `.` is the concatenation operator in PHP.

```
if(sha1($json . $secret) == $_POST['signature'])
```

Comment: This is just a short sample they show inside of their API document so I am not sure if it is showing the whole code in which they use.

Comment: OKay, lets get real. What is the output you are getting from their server?

Comment: I am going to sound like an idiot but how do I find that out, it does not show that information in my access logs.

Comment: *LOLz, don't worry, you are newbie, so you are excused*. You can check it via `Firebug's Net` tab in Firefox or `Network` tab in Chrome Developer tools. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @kira423 And are you trying to concatenate or add? 
If concatenation, replace the `+` with `.` as `.` is the concatenation operator in PHP.

Comment: It wouldn't make any sense to add nothing there. `sha1()` takes a string as an argument and a `string` + `string` is always 0.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I am using Chrome can you explain what exactly I need to do?

Comment: @kira423 Press F12, you will get a small screen in the bottom. Click on `Network`. Now try to load the page and there will be an activity in the `Network`. Click on it. Get the response. Post it in the question.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have done this, but I do not believe it is much help.

Comment: Get the response na. What is the server response. Well, am not able to explain more than this. Try finding out and update it in your answer, only then anyone could solve it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have added new information that may be of a bit more use

Answer (score 1):

**A complete edit has been made to this answer**

What you are required to do is to get the JSON data sent to you via POST-request and validate the signature with the payload and the secret key. The JSON is brought to you as raw HTTP POST data (*I'm not sure if this is the correct term*) and therefore it is not accessible through PHP's `$_POST` - global. So here is the solution:

```
$myJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');

$decodedJSON = json_decode($myJSON);

if (sha1($decodedJSON['payload'] . $secret) == $decodedJSON['signature']) {
  /* 
     If you need to do some database actions or such prior to sending the 
     response 200, you can do it here. Just don't output anything to the 
     screen before.
  */
  header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
}
else {
  // sha1 test failed, do something else here
}
```

Comment: You know I thought the same thing, but this script came straight from them so I didn't think anything more about it, but seeing as it doesn't work I should have changed that at the start of the trouble, but with it not getting the information it won't help until everything else gets fixed, thanks for reminding me though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ($json+$secret) is messing up your data-structure. Try $json['secret'] = NUMBER or $json->secret = NUMBER